# How do you update an environment variable from inside an Exec task?

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to pipe the output from a command to an Environment variable thus:

```
<Exec Command="for /f &quot;tokens=*&quot; %%i in ('svn info') do SET SVNINFO=%%i" />
```

and then use SVNINFO as a property in MSBuild.

While the command line counterpart:

for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('svn info') do SET SVNINFO=%i

works, the change in the value of the Environment variable when called from the Exec does not persist. (I am not able to obtain its value as a property.) Am I missing something here? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Feedback on my answer would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with .NET 4.5 you can capture output of the `Exec` task using its `ConsoleOutput` parameter by setting `ConsoleToMsBuild="true"` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task)). For example, the following target captures `%TIME%` value into the `Time` MSBuild property:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="echo %TIME%" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="Time" />
    </Exec>
    <Message Text="Current time is $(Time)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the Exec Task Output is a better way:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DefaultTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Exe">
        <Exec Command="echo %PATH%">
            <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" PropertyName="ExecOutput" />
        </Exec>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="DefaultTarget" DependsOnTargets="Exe">
        <Message Text="Result from Exec is $(ExecOutput)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: It does not work, msbuild's exec is too braindead to be able to grab the output